# mod_rewrite in alias directory not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a wp blog which lives under /var/www/mysite.com/blog and is accessible via www.mysite.com/blog

When visiting www.mysite.com/blog/ I see the index page, but all links on subdirectories are no longer working eg: www.mysite.com/blog/my-great-article is throwing (apache log):

```
File does not exist: /var/www/mysite.com/web/blog/my-great-article, 
     referer: http://www.mysite.com/blog/
```

vhost:

```
Alias /blog "/var/www/mysite.com/web/blog"
<Location "/blog">
    Allow from all
    AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 html htm
</Location>
```

.htacess in /blog dir:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does the configuration work when you put it inside the main config instead of `.htaccess`, and do you have an `AllowOverride` directive allowing the use of `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Shane's comment is likely to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and What helped in my case was to add `RewriteBase` in the .htaccess of the domain alias root

```
RewriteBase /blog
```

Withought the trailing slash, and also in RewriteRule to reference `index.php` instead of `/blog/index.php`